# Changing React state after some other state has changed in 1 render

Tags: reactjs

Assume I have 2 React components:

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0)
  
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(0)}>Page 0</button>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(1)}>Page 1</button>
        </div>
        <Page page={page} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

and **Page.jsx**

```
function Page({ page }) {
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)
    
    return (
        <div>
        Counter: {counter}
        <button onClick={() => setCounter(c => c+1)}>Increase Counter</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now I want to reset the `counter` state at **Page.jsx** whenever I change a page, so in order to do so I added the following `useEffect` to **Page.jsx**:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(0)
}, [page])
```

The issue is, that the useEffect occur in the 2nd render cycle, so when changing a page, it would first move to the new page with the stale counter value, and only then it would re-render the component with counter=0

An example (open console log): https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-sun-8tlwcy?file=/src/Page.js

The issue that it can cause a user experience issue, the user might see for a fraction of time the stale counter instead of counter=0.

The question is how can I do that in 1 render time? without moving the setCounter outside of `Page.jsx`? This example is simple but in my real app there are many sub-components inside Page that recursively have sub-components, and I don't want to aggregate unused states higher in the hierarchy just to solve that issue.

Comment: Have you tried to read [this](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state)?

Comment: You don't need an effect, just pass page as the key to Page

Comment: Thank you nullptr for the answer and Arkellys for the source! it's exactly what I needed and they use the same example idea as I just described!

Please make an answer so I could accept it :-)